# How to rotate only y axis

Tags: css

I am trying to rotate a cube only y axis but it also transform x axis. This cube rotates correctly if I set the width 300px. but I need to keep width 600px. I also try transform origin to center but it doesn't work.

I also change the prespective but the problem still occur. I can't figure out what to change.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
</head>

<body>
<!--   CUBE PART  -->

<section id="cube">
   <div id="wrapper">
       <div class="box">
           <div class="front same"></div>
           <div class="back same"></div>
           <div class="left same"></div>
           <div class="right same"></div>
           <div class="bottom same"></div>
           <div class="top same"></div>
       </div>
   </div>
</section>

<!--   END OF CUBE PART-->

<script src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my css.

```
*{
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
/*CUBE PART CSS*/
#cube{
position: relative;
height: 300px;
background: red;
}

#wrapper {
position: absolute;
top: 100%;
left: 50%;
-webkit-perspective: 1500px;
perspective: 1800px;
}

.box {
display: inline-block;
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
transform-style: preserve-3d;
position: relative;
-webkit-animation: cube 5s linear infinite;
animation: cube 50s linear infinite;
}

.same {
position: absolute;
height: 300px;
width: 600px;
background: red;
}
.front{
background: blue;
-webkit-transform: translateX(-150px) translateY(-150px) translateZ(300px);
transform: translateX(-150px) translateY(-150px) translateZ(300px);
}
.back{
background: green;
-webkit-transform: translateX(-150px) translateY(-150px) translateZ(-150px);
transform: translateX(-150px) translateY(-150px) translateZ(-300px);
}
.left{
background: yellow;
-webkit-transform: translateY(-150px) rotateY(90deg);
transform: translateY(-150px) translateX(150px)rotateY(90deg)
}
.right{
background: purple;
-webkit-transform: translateX(-300px) translateY(-150px) rotateY(90deg);
transform: translateX(-450px) translateY(-150px) rotateY(90deg)
}
.top{
background: orange;
height: 600px;
-webkit-transform: translateY(-300px) translateX(-150px)rotateX(90deg);
transform: translateY(-300px) translateX(-150px) rotateX(90deg) translateZ(150px);
}
.bottom{
background: black;
height: 600px;
-webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateX(-150px);
transform: rotateX(90deg) translateX(-150px) translateZ(150px)
}
/*ANIMATION PART*/
/*CUBE ANIMATION*/
@-webkit-keyframes cube{
0%{


    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0,0,0,0deg);


    transform: rotate3d(0,0,0,0deg);
}
100%{
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0,1,0,360deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0,1,0,360deg);
}
}
@keyframes cube{
0%{


    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0,0,0,0deg);


    transform: rotate3d(0,0,0,0deg);
}
100%{
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0,1,0,360deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0,1,0,360deg);
}

}
 /*CUBE ANIMATION ENDS*/
```

Comment: Now its rotating in x -axis ? you want to make it in y-axis ?

Comment: No its rotating in y axis but not centered. it also moves around x axis

Comment: @JithinB can you suggest any solve?

Comment: Do i need to change the perspective?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solve which work for me. In which div i give animation property in that div i give height and width property same as each side of my cube's height and width. And i keep each side of the cube relatively centered to the animating div. That's how i can achieve my solution. let me show my code. If further improvement possible please let me know. 
Here is HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
</head>

<body>
<!--   CUBE PART  -->
<section id="cube">
   <div id="wrapper">
       <div class="box">
           <div class="front same"></div>
           <div class="back same"></div>
           <div class="left same"></div>
           <div class="right same"></div>
           <div class="bottom same"></div>
           <div class="top same"></div>
       </div>
   </div>
  </section>

  <!--   END OF CUBE PART-->
  <script src="js/index.js"></script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Here is CSS:

```
*{
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
/*CUBE PART CSS*/
#cube{
position: relative;
height: 300px;
background: red;
width: 100%;
}

#wrapper {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 35%;
-webkit-perspective: 2000px;
perspective: 2000px;
-webkit-perspective-origin: center;
perspective-origin: center;
}

.box {
position: relative;
background: teal;
height: 300px;
width: 600px;
left: -100px;
-webkit-transform-origin: center;
transform-origin: center;
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
transform-style: preserve-3d;
-webkit-animation: cube 5s linear infinite;
animation: cube 5s linear infinite;
}

.same {
position: absolute;
height: 300px;
width: 600px;
background: red;
}
.front{
background: blue;
-webkit-transform: translateX(-150px) translateY(-150px) translateZ(300px);
transform: translateX(0px) translateY(00px) translateZ(300px);
}
.back{
background: green;
-webkit-transform: translateX(-150px) translateY(-150px) translateZ(-150px);
transform: translateX(0px) translateY(0px) translateZ(-300px);
}
.left{
background: yellow;
-webkit-transform: translateY(-150px) rotateY(90deg);
transform: translateY(0px) translateX(300px)rotateY(90deg);
}
.right{
background: purple;
-webkit-transform: translateX(-300px) translateY(-150px) rotateY(90deg);
transform: translateX(-300px) translateY(0px) rotateY(90deg);
}
.top{
background: orange;
height: 600px;
-webkit-transform: translateY(-300px) translateX(-150px)rotateX(90deg);
transform: translateY(0px) translateX(0px) rotateX(90deg) translateZ(300px);
}
.bottom{
background: black;
height: 600px;
-webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateX(-150px);
transform: translateX(0px) rotateX(90deg)  translateZ(0px);
}
/*ANIMATION PART*/
/*CUBE ANIMATION*/
@-webkit-keyframes cube{
0%{

    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0,0,0,0deg);

    transform: rotate3d(0,0,0,0deg);
}
100%{
     -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0,1,0,360deg);
     transform: rotate3d(0,1,0,360deg);   
}

}
@keyframes cube{
0%{

    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0,0,0,0deg);

    transform: rotate3d(0,0,0,0deg);
}
100%{
     -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0,1,0,360deg);
     transform: rotate3d(0,1,0,360deg);   
}

}
/*CUBE ANIMATION ENDS*/
```